# from_utc_timestamp not taking daylight saving time into account

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert timestamp in UTC to MST or EST time, but its not taking daylight saving into account.
Also is it better to use MST or EST or should we use "America/Phoenix' or "America/New York".

Please help.

Thanks,
Naveed

Comment: You should provide a minimum reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @alexott `America/Phoenix` has not observed daylight saving since 1967 so the issue still exists for 'MST'.

Comment: If you put "MST" or "EST" or "PST" you will always get standard time and NOT get daylight savings time. They stand for "Eastern STANDARD Time" etc. The time zones for daylight savings time are MDT, EDT, PDT, etc., or i.e. "Eastern DAYLIGHT Time."

These are usually *not* what you want and only exist as references for more useful time zone indicators such as America/Los Angeles (for Pacific supporting DST) or America/New York (for Eastern supporting DST). 

Finally America/Phoenix is specifically for most of Arizona (and apparently some weird town in BC) which doesn't support DST.

Comment: You would probably be fine using MST instead of America/Phoenix, because it never changes (although, if it did change, it would become wrong, while America/Phoenix would likely update) but this does *not* hold true for any place that observes DST, you should use the America/... version.

Answer (score 3):

Use **`America/New_York`** for `Eastren` and **`America/Phoenix`** for `Mountain` timezones, Spark **`from_utc_timestamp`** function will automatically gets daylight timing covered for us.

**`Example:`**

```
#set timezone for the session    
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'America/New_York')

#daylight saving time i.e -4:00 hrs from utc
spark.sql("""select current_timestamp as current_ts,from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp,"America/New_York") utc_to_est""").show(10,False)
#+-----------------------+-----------------------+
#|current_ts             |utc_to_est             |
#+-----------------------+-----------------------+
#|2020-05-10 19:04:28.369|2020-05-10 15:04:28.369|
#+-----------------------+-----------------------+

#after daylight saving time that will be -5:00 hrs from utc.
spark.sql("""select from_utc_timestamp("2020-12-10 15:04:28.369","America/New_York") utc_to_est""").show(10,False)
#+-----------------------+
#|utc_to_est             |
#+-----------------------+
#|2020-12-10 10:04:28.369|
#+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Just want to confirm whether this function always take daylight saving into account when converting the timestamps.

Comment: @NabeelKhanGhauri -- it does.  Also, FYI, if it makes the code more obvious to all involved, I sometimes use `EST5EDT`, which is explicitly providing both daylight and standard ... for the Eastern time zone.

Comment: `America/Phoenix` does not observe daylight saving so the issue still exists for 'MST'

Comment: You should *only* use America/Phoenix for *Arizona* (areas not in Navajo territory). Other places in Mountain Time observe DST, and if you use America/Phoenix in those places, you will be wrong half the year. Use America/Denver or America/Boise for those places instead.