# Timestamp Timezone Wrong/Missing in Spark/Databricks SQL Output

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

When converting a timestamp between timezones in databricks/spark sql, the timezone itself seems lost in the end result, and I can't seem to either keep it or add it back.

I have a bunch of UTC times and am using the [from_utc_timetamp()](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/from_utc_timestamp.html) to convert them to a different timezone based on another field. The result is calculated correctly, but if I output it with a timezone it shows as UTC. It seems the conversion is done correctly but the end result has no timezone stored with it (affirmed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691202/does-spark-sql-timestamp-datatype-actually-store-timezone)), so it uses the server zone for the timezone in all cases.

**Example**: Using the following SQL:

```
createTimestampUTC,
v.timezone,
date_format(from_utc_timestamp(createTimestampUTC, v.timezone),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:s Z") createTimestampLocal,
```

I get the following:

[image: Result of query]

You can see that the third column has done the conversions correctly for the timezones, but the output itself still shows as being in UTC timezone.

Repeating this with a [lowercase z](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) in the [date_format](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/date_format.html) function shows the same; namely, the conversions occur but the end result is still treated as UTC.

```
createTimestampUTC,
v.timezone,
date_format(from_utc_timestamp(createTimestampUTC, v.timezone),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:s z") createTimestampLocal,
```

[image: Query result with lowercase z in date_format]

I can also use an `O` in the format output instead of a `Z` or `z`, but this just gives me GMT instead of UTC; same output basically.

All the [databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-conf-mgmt-set-timezone.html) or [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956623/how-apply-a-different-timezone-to-a-timestamp-in-pyspark) I can find seem to treat printing timezones as a matter of setting the spark server time and outputting that way, or doing the conversion [without keeping the resulting timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719585/from-utc-timestamp-not-taking-daylight-saving-time-into-account). I'm trying to convert to multiple *different* timezones though, and to keep the timezone in the output. I need to generate the end result in this format:

[image: Desired timestamp output format]

Is there a way to do this? How do I either keep the timezone after the conversion or add it back in the format I need based on the timezone column I have? Given that the conversion works, and that I can output the end result with a +0000 on it, all the functionality to do this seems there, how do I put it together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark does not support `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` datatype as defined by ANSI SQL. Even though there are some functions that convert the timestamp across timezones, this information is never stored. Databricks documentation on [timestamps](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/dates-timestamps.html#ansi-sql-and-spark-sql-timestamps) explains:

> Spark SQL defines the timestamp type as **TIMESTAMP WITH SESSION TIME
> ZONE**, which is a combination of the fields (YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR,
> MINUTE, SECOND, SESSION TZ) where the YEAR through SECOND field
> identify a time instant in the UTC time zone, and where SESSION TZ is
> taken from the SQL config spark.sql.session.timeZone.

In your case `spark.sql.session.timeZone` is UTC and `Z` symbol in datetime pattern will always return UTC. Therefore you will never get a correct behavior with `date_format` if you deal with multiple timezones in a single query.

The only thing you can do is to explicitly store timezone information in a column and manually append it for display.

```
concat(
   date_format(from_utc_timestamp(createTimestampUTC, v.timezone), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:s "),
   v.timezone
) createTimestampLocal
```

This will display `2022-03-01T16:47:22.000 America/New_York`. If you need an offset (`-05:00`) you will need to write a UDF to do the conversion and use Python or Scala native libraries that handle datetime conversions.